# How to apply latitude and longitude resolution to image mosaic in geoserver based on zoom level

Tags: geoserver

How we can skip points in the raster layer (created using image mosaic) based on zoom?
I think it's called latitude/longitude resolution or sometimes grid step.

Tried Point symbolizer/ filters in SLD, but not sure how to use filters to skip points.

Edit -
I created store and layers as mentioned in below link
https://geoserver.geo-solutions.it/multidim/multidim/mosaic_config/netcdf_mosaic.html

Everything works fine. Now the issue is all data is shown.
The default netcdf spatial resolution is 0.4 and I want to change this as per zoom levels. for ex for zoom 1-5=1, zoom 5-10=0.75 and so on

Comment: rasters have pixels not points - may be you can [edit] your question to make what you are trying to do clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution, It's not what I need but still solves the issue.
The solution is to use wms_scale_denominator & Categories.

SLD block -

```
<ogc:Function name="parameter">
    <ogc:Literal>scale</ogc:Literal>
    <ogc:Function name="Categorize">
        <ogc:Function name="env">
            <ogc:Literal>wms_scale_denominator</ogc:Literal>
        </ogc:Function>
        <ogc:Literal>16</ogc:Literal>
        <ogc:Literal>100000</ogc:Literal>
        <ogc:Literal>8</ogc:Literal>
        <ogc:Literal>500000</ogc:Literal>
        <ogc:Literal>2</ogc:Literal>
        <ogc:Literal>1000000</ogc:Literal>
        <ogc:Literal>0.5</ogc:Literal>
        <ogc:Literal>5000000</ogc:Literal>
        <ogc:Literal>0.2</ogc:Literal>
        <ogc:Literal>10000000</ogc:Literal>
        <ogc:Literal>0.1</ogc:Literal>
        <ogc:Literal>20000000</ogc:Literal>
        <ogc:Literal>0.05</ogc:Literal>
        <ogc:Literal>60000000</ogc:Literal>
        <ogc:Literal>0.02</ogc:Literal>
    </ogc:Function>
</ogc:Function>
```